# EF 4.0 - another way to use Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do something like this:

```
context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);
```

I use EF 4.0 so I know that I can use the `context.ObjectStateManager` to achieve the same things

I don't see any way to set the values. I have `ChangeObjectState`, `ChangeRelationshipState`, `ChangeRelationshipState` functions available.

In fact I have this error : `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`

So I need to modify the entity instead of attaching it so solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(oldEntity).ApplyCurrentValues(newEntity);
```